# How do we design a LISN circuit for DC-DC converter?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, emc, emi-filtering

I am trying to understand about LISN (Line Impedance Stabilization Network). When i research online, i find different LISN circuit based on the standards and specifications. On what criteria i should choose the circuit ? What are the conditions should i take into mind when i draw a LISN circuit ? [image] [image]

Comment: Choose the one that fits your standard seems to be the best option.

Comment: You might define LSIN for those of us who don't know. Just for our education, even though it won't help answer the question.

Comment: @BrianCarlton it's added to an answer

Answer (score 2):

> On what criteria i should choose the circuit ?

- If your measurement receiver is 50 ohms then it's likely that R2 (in
  your 2nd diagram) is also 50 ohms.
- C2 is chosen so that the lowest frequency of interest does not get attenuated by R2 too much
- L1 is there to prevent the power supply shorting out the signal from the DUT so think about your lowest frequency of interest and make L1 large enough to prevent the power supply attenuating that signal by very much.
- C1 and R1 are there to offer a low impedance at measurement frequencies thus, if the power supply (on its long cable) has a high impedance at high frequencies, there are no strange reflections that might affect how L1 works. For instance, if the power cable and supply together become an impedance transformer they might "project" a capacitance to be in series with the inductor (L1) that causes a resonance and ruins your measurement fidelity.

Also note that L1 is likely a series combination of mH, uH and possibly even nH in order to give a wideband impedance from kHz to GHz.

Answer (score 2):

Now I take a risk to get a burst of downvotes, but the basic theory is:

LISN (=Line Impedance Stabilization Network) is needed to measure how strong radio transmitter the device under the test (=DUT or EUT) is when the rf emission via the power supply wires is taken into the account. LISN lets DUT get its power supply undisturbed and at the same time directs all rf emissions to a standard resistive load. The measuring equipment (=spectrum analyzer or a frequency band selective rf Vrms meter) measures what that standard load gets. Many measuring equipment have a low input resistance 50 Ohm. That must be taken into the account when selecting R1 in your diagram 1 or R2 in diagram 2.

To keep the measurements reliable, another function of the LISN is to prevent

- the rf signal from DUT to escape to the power supply wires and
- possible  external rf signals to enter to the measuring equipment from the power supply wires

The inductors in LISN choke rf, but let DC go and the capacitors let rf go, but stop DC. The extra resistors (R2 and R3 in your diagram 1 and R1 in diagram 2) keep the choked rf leakage loaded. That prevents the power supply wire lenght and power supply circuitry variations to affect on how the rf emission from DUT is totally loaded.

If you want to analyze, how your LISN performs, you must read the standard. Then you can simulate how much external rf from the power supply is attenuated and how much the rf emission from DUT to the measuring equipment is attenuated with diffrent resistances and reactances connected to the power supply wire terminals.

DC current can saturate ferrites. You must use inductors that do not lose their inductance at the needed current. The whole circuitry must be designed for the whole interesting frequency band. That's not trivial at all.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i got some idea about how it works. But when and how do i decide between single or double or multi stage LISN circuit ?

Comment: @SaikumarNatarajan Simulate the effectivity - how much uncertainty (variation of the rf power transfer to the measuring equipment)  is caused when the power supply+its wires vary from rf short circuit to infinite impedance and be also in turn reactive. Also you should have some data of the external rf fields that must be prevented to enter into the measuring equipment. I cannot know anything about your test environment. But the attenuation must be high enough.